# How to keep me logged in on a php form

Tags: php, html

I created a login page to a php form that I also created. Whenever I fill the form with the required fields, I get redirected to a 'Thank you for your submission' page, that has the link 'Go Back to Form'.

The problem is, when I press the 'Go Back to Form' link, it assumes that I am not logged in anymore, and so I get directed to a white page instead.

Login Page Code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitlogin'])) {

    $username1= $_POST['username'];
    $pass1= $_POST['password'];

    if($username1==$nomepass && $pass1==$passpass)  {

        $_SESSION['CurrentUser']= $username1;

        echo '**HTML FORM**';
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}

?>
```

Form 'Thank you' Page:

```
HTML code Inside PHP echo
...
echo ' <p> <a href="login.php">Back to login page</a> </p>' ;
```

Comment: Lookup session management in google.

Comment: You should be checking if the session is set inside every page.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 what I mean is, it redirects me to the page where I want to go, which is the login.php, but instead of showing me the form I created, it shows a white page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the login form and subsequent pages using sessions, put an `if` statement to check if the session that tells that a person has logged in is set. Then, it will redirect you to a home page or whatever page you want if you are logged in.

That way, if you are not logged in, you can login otherwise, it will redirect you

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])){
    // redirect to some page
}

else{
  // do something else
}
```

You could also make that line to read as:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser']) && !empty($_SESSION['CurrentUser']))
```

Comment: `If(isset($_SESSION['blah blah whatever'])){...}` - you're missing a bracket `If($_SESSION['blah blah whatever']` <= on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we can use the session and call it on every page where I wan to allow the register user, for example..

This is you php code

```
if (isset($_POST['submitlogin'])) {

    $username1= $_POST['username'];
    $pass1= $_POST['password'];

    if($username1==$nomepass && $pass1==$passpass)  {

        $_SESSION['CurrentUser']= $username1;

        header('location:index.php');
    }
```

Now you can code in the index page like this...

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['currentUser']))

{
header('location:signin.php');

}

?>
```

if the session is set tyhen the above code will keep you login otherwise you will redirect to signin page..